# I Cant find the right path for custom html file in ADT BUNDLE

Tags: java, android, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to load my custom html file on android `webview` project. 
The problem is, using ADT BUNDLE and when I try load the `url`

It says FILE NOT FOUND.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
     public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl){
     **webview.loadUrl("file://asset/error.html");**
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that path to file is correct: `file:///asset/error.html`.
Also, can you display the hierarchy in which your files are being stored?

Answer (score 0):

As I think webview needs url so instead of

```
webview.loadUrl("file://asset/error.html");
```

use ip address

```
webview.loadUrl("192.../asset/error.html");
```

this is working perfect